# How do I read multiple files with some pattern in loop?

Tags: matlab, io

I have 51 files in my ../Data/ directory. They are named as output_t0.dat, output_t1.dat, output_t2.dat and so on till output_t50.dat.
I have a function that takes filepath as argument and opens it using fopen.

```
  fname4='/home/...../Data/output_t46.dat';
  fname3='/home/...../Data/output_t47.dat';
  fname1='/home/...../Data/output_t48.dat';
  fname2='/home/...../Data/output_t49.dat';

  D1=getvar(fname1,sim,mesh,V,sim.nsaves);
  D2=getvar(fname2,sim,mesh,V,sim.nsaves);
  D3=getvar(fname3,sim,mesh,V,sim.nsaves);
  D4=getvar(fname4,sim,mesh,V,sim.nsaves);
```

Ignore the other arguments. Now have to open all the 51 files and save it into a matrix instead of individual variables D1, D2.
I tried this:

```
list_of_files=dir(fullfile('/home/.../Data/'));
for i=3:length(list_of_files)

    list_of_files(i).name
end
```

But this just gives me file name and I can't call it in function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Load command in matlab:

```
>> load my_xy.dat;     %  read data into the my_xy matrix
>> x = my_xy(:,1);     %  copy first column of my_xy into x
>> y = my_xy(:,2);     %  and second column into y
```

when you use load command it automatically create a matrix with the name of the file,
check this sample for more reference:
http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/MATLAB/plotting/loadingPlotData.html#loadAndPlot

Regards